# A method equivalent to conjugate gradient for quadratic function

Tags: optimization, algorithms, nonlinear-optimization, numerical-optimization

Consider a method where the first iteration is a steepest descent iteration with exact line search and subsequent iterations have form $$x_{i+1} = x_i - \alpha_i f^{'}(x_i) - \beta_i(x_i - x_{i-1})$$
where $\alpha_i$ and $\beta_i$ are obtained by two dimensional minimization (that is they minimize value of $f$ on corresponding plane).

Show that if $f$ is a quadratic function then this method is the same as conjugate gradient method.

Comment: This is a very interesting question. I'd never heard of this way of looking at the conjugate gradient method, and it seems quite illuminating. Where did you come across this question? Is it from a book?

Comment: It was posed by lecturer during a lecture for my optimization course.

Comment: Mind saying who the lecturer was or what course it was?

Comment: It is a numerical optimization course at University of Wrocław.

Comment: So it seems like this problem is saying that the conjugate gradient method is just Polyak's "[heavy ball](https://web.stanford.edu/class/msande318/notes/notes-first-order-smooth.pdf)" method, and the step size and momentum parameters are both chosen by "exact search". How did I never hear about this.

Comment: Anyway, I think that what you should do is assume that $f(x) = \frac12 x^T A x - x^T b$, where $A$ is a symmetric positive definite matrix and $b$ is a column vector. The gradient of $f$ is $\nabla f(x) = Ax - b$. You want to minimize $L(\alpha, \beta) = f(x_i - \alpha \nabla f(x_i) - \beta (x_i - x_{i-1}))$ with respect to $\alpha$ and $\beta$. So just simplify the expression for $L(\alpha, \beta)$, set the partial derivatives of $L$ with respect to $\alpha$ and $\beta$ equal to $0$, and then solve for $\alpha$ and $\beta$. I haven't tried it yet but hopefully that will just work.